# SQL Server - Join tables so multiple rows become one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make a Join statement that will combine two tables, one being for employee information and the other for job role info.  The structure of the tables is as follows:

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

I would like to join these two tables in such a way that JobKey and JobValue would be the same row as the associated employee, and not create duplicate rows.  Normally, a join statement would create this:

[image]

Instead, what i would like is something like this:

[image]

Is there an effective way to do this?

Edit:
Here is the query I'm currently using to join them:

```
select * from testTable1 as a left join testTable2 as b on a.EmployeeName = b.EmployeeName
```

Comment: how are you joining the tables?

Comment: Are there maximum 2 JobKeys per employee?  And are those limited to only the 2 JobKeys "Duty" and "Role"? Or are there more?  If the amount of JobKeys per employee is unknown, then this probably requires Dynamic Sql.

Comment: Something seems pretty off in your desired output. You have John Doe doing all the work and Jane is not even in the result set.

Comment: Why do you store the names in twice, in different tables?

Comment: @jarlh Good point.  Table2 should just have the EmployeeID as foreign key. Instead of duplicating the EmployeeName.   Probably the same thing with the JobKey, which is a name.  This goes against the good practise of normalization.

Comment: @LukStorms  In hindsight, your right, I could do that.  I'll try it.

The names were to indicate which employee each key value pair applies to.  The key and value (JobKey and JobValue) can be anything, so I though to link it to the other table by the name.  Eventually, there are plans to use * in place of defined parameter for that link, which will indicate that the key value pair applies to all employees.  That is beyond the scope of this question though.

Comment: It'll be a good lesson for you. In a normalized model you can change a name in 1 place, and then it won't break the queries that link the tables.  Else you could have to update the name in all the tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select t1.*, t2.jobkey_1, t2.jobvalue_1, t2.jobkey_2, t2.jobkey_2
from table1 t1 left join
     (select t2.employeename, 
             max(case when seqnum = 1 then jobkey end) as jobkey_1,
             max(case when seqnum = 1 then jobvalue end) as jobvalue_1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then jobkey end) as jobkey_2,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then jobvalue end) as jobvalue_2,
      from (select t2.*, row_number() over (partition by employeename order by rowid) as seqnum
            from table2 t2
           ) t2
       group by employeename
      ) t2;
```

Note:  You appear to be using the employee name as the join key between the tables.  You should really be using the employee id.